WNet* Network Independent but WNetEnumResource not reliable?
It seems something changed on newer Windows versions where the WNetEnumResource (net view) doesn't show much of anything.  Yet you can go to Windows explorer and open the network tree item and the items show.
WNet* being network independent seems like it should be the trouble free way to access any network in Windows and functions like WNetEnumResource should just work, but it's not.  Is there some new function to use?
TIA!!

According to the Doc:WNetEnumResourceA function
The WNetEnumResource function does not enumerate users connected to a share; you can call the NetConnectionEnum function to accomplish this task. To enumerate hidden shares, call the NetShareEnum function.
And you couldrefer to the official sample :Enumerating Network Resources to enumerate all the resources on a network.

@Jeaninez-MSFT I use WNetEnumResource to find the computers on the network, like "net view" would.  It just doesn't work like it did in prior Windows versions.  The list of computers in "network" must come from something else now ...

Whether have you tried to use NetShareEnum
